# Electron Tunneling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-tunneling

An electron dot is a Quantum confinement where the motion of the electron is constrained in all the three dimensions ,which means that the electron has zero potential energy and supposed to be at rest (I am  not sure !).Then how come is it possible for the electron to tunnel through the barrier and reach the opposite side ?? From where does it acquire energy (despite the fact that the energy is less than the barrier energy)??

Comment: Hint: What does the HUP say about a particle whose position is strongly constrained?

Comment: The whole point of [tunnelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling) is precisely that the particle energy is less than the barrier.

Comment: So is it right  if I say that though the electron's motion is constrained in all the three dimensions, it still possess energy which is less than the barrier potential energy due to which it tunnels?